# How to Filter Data in a Single MySQL Database Field that has Multiple Entries

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, google-sheets, export-to-excel

On our Wordpress site, we use a plugin called [s2member](https://s2member.com/) and it stores the levels (roles) of our clients as well as the times they were assigned a specific level in our database. I would like to create a table that shows when a user was assigned a specific level.  I'm having a challenge getting the data I need because of the way the data is stored in the field.  It stores all of the levels along with the associated dates and times when a user's level was changed in one field.  In addition, it stores all of the times as Unix timestamps.  Here's an example of a typical field associated with a client:

```
a:20:{s:15:"1562695223.0001";s:6:"level0";s:15:"1562695223.0002";s:6:"level1";s:15:"1562695223.0003";s:6:"level2";s:15:"1562695223.0004";s:6:"level3";s:15:"1577906312.0001";s:11:"ccap_prepay";s:15:"1596575898.0001";s:12:"-ccap_prepay";s:15:"1596575898.0002";s:13:"ccap_graduate";s:15:"1596575898.0003";s:11:"ccap_prepay";s:15:"1596575898.0004";s:7:"-level3";s:15:"1597196952.0001";s:14:"-ccap_graduate";s:15:"1597196952.0002";s:12:"-ccap_prepay";s:15:"1597196952.0003";s:13:"ccap_graduate";s:15:"1597196952.0004";s:11:"ccap_prepay";s:15:"1598382433.0001";s:14:"-ccap_graduate";s:15:"1598382433.0002";s:12:"-ccap_prepay";s:15:"1598382433.0003";s:11:"ccap_prepay";s:15:"1598382433.0004";s:6:"level3";s:15:"1605290551.0001";s:12:"-ccap_prepay";s:15:"1605290551.0002";s:11:"ccap_prepay";s:15:"1605290551.0003";s:13:"ccap_graduate";}
```

There are four columns in this table:

- `umeta_id`
- `user_id`
- `meta_key`
- `meta_value`

The data above is stored in the `meta_value` column.

You'll notice that it also has multiple `ccap_*` entries. CCAP stands for custom capapability and I would like to be able to chart those assignments and associated times as well.

Do you have any idea how I can accomplish this?

Thank you for any help you can give.

I talked to an engineer about this and he told me that I would need to learn Python and I *believe* he said I would need to learn how to also use Pandas and Numpy to extract the data I need but he wasn't exactly sure.  I started taking a data analyst course on Coursera but I still haven't learned what I need to learn and it's already been several months.  It would be great if someone could provide a solution that I could implement more quickly and use on an ongoing basis.

If there's a way to accomplish my goal by exporting this table to a CSV file and using Microsoft Excel or Google Sheets, I'm open to that too.

Here's an image of the table (if it helps):
[image: Database table]

Here's an example of my desired output:

[image: Desired output]

In my desired output, I used Excel and created a column that converts the Unix timestamp to a short date and another column where I used a nested IF statement to convert the CCAP or level to its meaning that we understand internally.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to parse that string outside of PHP? If not - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: https://rextester.com/BPJA44038

Comment: @player0, I really appreciate this suggestion.  My desired output is a pivot table that shows the the various levels and ccaps per year/quarter/month.  I'll add an image of what I'd like to see.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thank you so much for this output.  I'm not a programmer or developer so I hadn't thought about using PHP but I really appreciate what you shared.  I used it to create a spreadsheet that helped me think more about my desired output.  I would like to use a helpful, repeatable method that will allow me to parse the information in the way in which you shared it so I can use Excel and eventually Preset (Apache Superset) to display the data in a Pivot table.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, please see my desired output image in my updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```php
<?php
$s = 'a:20:{s:15:"1562695223.0001";s:6:"level0";s:15:"1562695223.0002";s:6:"level1";s:15:"1562695223.0003";s:6:"level2";s:15:"1562695223.0004";s:6:"level3";s:15:"1577906312.0001";s:11:"ccap_prepay";s:15:"1596575898.0001";s:12:"-ccap_prepay";s:15:"1596575898.0002";s:13:"ccap_graduate";s:15:"1596575898.0003";s:11:"ccap_prepay";s:15:"1596575898.0004";s:7:"-level3";s:15:"1597196952.0001";s:14:"-ccap_graduate";s:15:"1597196952.0002";s:12:"-ccap_prepay";s:15:"1597196952.0003";s:13:"ccap_graduate";s:15:"1597196952.0004";s:11:"ccap_prepay";s:15:"1598382433.0001";s:14:"-ccap_graduate";s:15:"1598382433.0002";s:12:"-ccap_prepay";s:15:"1598382433.0003";s:11:"ccap_prepay";s:15:"1598382433.0004";s:6:"level3";s:15:"1605290551.0001";s:12:"-ccap_prepay";s:15:"1605290551.0002";s:11:"ccap_prepay";s:15:"1605290551.0003";s:13:"ccap_graduate";}';
$a = unserialize($s);
$csv = 'Timestamp,Date,Capability'."\n";
foreach ($a as $time => $ccap) {
   $csv .= $time . ',' . date('Y-m-d', $time) . ',' . $ccap . "\n";
}
echo $csv;
```

That'll give you a CSV you can open as a spreadsheet.

```
Timestamp,Date,Capability
1562695223.0001,2019-07-09,level0
1562695223.0002,2019-07-09,level1
1562695223.0003,2019-07-09,level2
1562695223.0004,2019-07-09,level3
1577906312.0001,2020-01-01,ccap_prepay
1596575898.0001,2020-08-04,-ccap_prepay
1596575898.0002,2020-08-04,ccap_graduate
1596575898.0003,2020-08-04,ccap_prepay
1596575898.0004,2020-08-04,-level3
1597196952.0001,2020-08-12,-ccap_graduate
1597196952.0002,2020-08-12,-ccap_prepay
1597196952.0003,2020-08-12,ccap_graduate
1597196952.0004,2020-08-12,ccap_prepay
1598382433.0001,2020-08-25,-ccap_graduate
1598382433.0002,2020-08-25,-ccap_prepay
1598382433.0003,2020-08-25,ccap_prepay
1598382433.0004,2020-08-25,level3
1605290551.0001,2020-11-13,-ccap_prepay
1605290551.0002,2020-11-13,ccap_prepay
1605290551.0003,2020-11-13,ccap_graduate
```

Or for an HTML table:

```php
$table = '<table>' . "\n". '<tr><th>Timestamp</th><th>Date</th><th>Capability</th></tr>' . "\n";
foreach ($a as $time => $cap) {
   $table .= '<tr><td>'. $time . '</td><td>' . date('Y-m-d', $time) . '</td><td>' . $cap . '</td></tr>' . "\n";
}
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>Timestamp</th><th>Date</th><th>Capability</th></tr>
<tr><td>1562695223.0001</td><td>2019-07-09</td><td>level0</td></tr>
<tr><td>1562695223.0002</td><td>2019-07-09</td><td>level1</td></tr>
<tr><td>1562695223.0003</td><td>2019-07-09</td><td>level2</td></tr>
<tr><td>1562695223.0004</td><td>2019-07-09</td><td>level3</td></tr>
<tr><td>1577906312.0001</td><td>2020-01-01</td><td>ccap_prepay</td></tr>
<tr><td>1596575898.0001</td><td>2020-08-04</td><td>-ccap_prepay</td></tr>
<tr><td>1596575898.0002</td><td>2020-08-04</td><td>ccap_graduate</td></tr>
<tr><td>1596575898.0003</td><td>2020-08-04</td><td>ccap_prepay</td></tr>
<tr><td>1596575898.0004</td><td>2020-08-04</td><td>-level3</td></tr>
<tr><td>1597196952.0001</td><td>2020-08-12</td><td>-ccap_graduate</td></tr>
<tr><td>1597196952.0002</td><td>2020-08-12</td><td>-ccap_prepay</td></tr>
<tr><td>1597196952.0003</td><td>2020-08-12</td><td>ccap_graduate</td></tr>
<tr><td>1597196952.0004</td><td>2020-08-12</td><td>ccap_prepay</td></tr>
<tr><td>1598382433.0001</td><td>2020-08-25</td><td>-ccap_graduate</td></tr>
<tr><td>1598382433.0002</td><td>2020-08-25</td><td>-ccap_prepay</td></tr>
<tr><td>1598382433.0003</td><td>2020-08-25</td><td>ccap_prepay</td></tr>
<tr><td>1598382433.0004</td><td>2020-08-25</td><td>level3</td></tr>
<tr><td>1605290551.0001</td><td>2020-11-13</td><td>-ccap_prepay</td></tr>
<tr><td>1605290551.0002</td><td>2020-11-13</td><td>ccap_prepay</td></tr>
<tr><td>1605290551.0003</td><td>2020-11-13</td><td>ccap_graduate</td></tr>
</table>
```